# How to add element to children of a specific inflated element?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout-inflater

I'm working on a simple timetable app and I represent the days as *Linear Layouts* and the subjects as *Buttons*. I want to generate both the days and the subjects programmatically through inflation, so I created 2 axmls for a day element and a subject:

Day with a title:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDay"
android:layout_margin="20px">
<Button
android:text="Day"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/IDDay"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="20px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

A subject:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="Large Text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

I can inflate any number of new day elements so that they are added to a predefined *Linear Layout* and I can add the subjects with the following code:

```
//adding a new day element
View day = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DayElement, FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutTimeTable));

//adding a subject to the day
View subject = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SubjectEntry, FindViewById<LinearLayout>(day.Id));
```

My problem is that I want to add the button to the *Linear Layout* child of the axml representing the day, something like (day.Id.specificElement). I can reference the *Linear Layout* child of the infalted day element directly:

```
View subject = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SubjectEntry, FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutDay));
```

but this way all the butons are added to the first day element and I need a method to add this infalted button element to the child of a previously inflated element. How should I approach this?

### **UPDATE**

I also tried to set the context as the second day element, but the button was added to the first one all the same:

```
LinearLayout layout = day2.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutDay);
View subject = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SubjectEntry, layout);
```

### **UPDATE**

It seems that the code regarding *LinearLayout layout* does not mean that find the view with the specified ID **inside the view of** the specified parent view (in this case, day2), as I previously suspected.
Coming from a C# Unity background where every element can be accesed a similar way, I expected to have many such elements with the same ID inside separate day elements (so a day1.linearLayoutDay, a day2.linearLayoutDay etc.) so I could have access to them easily, but this is not how C# Xamarin.Android appears to operate. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution and although it is not at all elegant, it seems to work for now, so I decided I post it here, in case someone finds it useful.
After hours of googling, I realized that my Xamarin xml knowledge is simply not enough to solve the problem that way, so I unearthed my Unity Code-Behind knoweldge and came up with something really simple. The following code generates 5 linear layouts to a preexisting parent layout then populates them with 4 buttons from the designed xml file:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //add new elements to a collection
            week.Add(LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.DayElement, FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutTimeTable)));
            //define new LL
            LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(this);
            //assign the new LL the desired xml
            lin = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutDay);
            //set its ID to smth fathomable
            lin.Id = i;

            //add 4 subjects of the predefined xml to every LL
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                View subject = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SubjectEntry, FindViewById<LinearLayout>(i));
            }
        }
```

This seems to solve the problem of how to inflate the same xml element with a unique ID that can be referenced properly. 
Feel free to criticise this, I'm still interested in how I could make this elegantly from xml (if it is possible). Of course, one would have to temper with this to be able to data-bind it.